# jpegs created by Gimp unable to be read

Tags: gimp, jpeg

Just upgraded Ubuntu to 14.04 and Gimp to 2.8.10. Have used Gimp for photo editing for some years with no previous problems. Now when I edit a jpeg photo and export to jpeg or even overwrite the original jpeg the file is not able to be read on other systems. eg can read the jpegs straight from the camera on the smart TV or the photo print facility but **not** after they have been edited in Gimp. The edited files can be read on my laptop in Image Viewer or Shotwell or even on my wife's Win8 laptop. Very frustrating as I have photos I want to take to be printed

Comment: I just tried this ubuntu 14.04 / gimp 2.8.10, and was not able to duplicate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your devices do probably not like the Progressive JPEG files GIMP 2.8 writes by default. It's not like this is anything new, so there isn't a real excuse for their manufacturers to not support this, but well...

You can change this in the JPEG export dialog:

1. deactivate the Progressive option
2. save those settings as the defaults for JPEG export

There was a bug that prevented step 2 from working, if you encounter that make sure to update to the the most recent 2.8 version (at the moment, this is 2.8.14).

[image: GIMP JPEG export dialog]

Comment: Thanks, didn't have a problem with reading these progressive files.  However, noticed that reading them from disk was a lot slower, and was tired of having to disable progressive every single time, and sometimes forgetting.  Had seen those buttons below but had tuned them out, haha.  Was expecting defaults in the main preferences instead.